# simulate paste from clipboard (CTRL + V / SHIFT + INS) in a MobaXterm macro

Tags: keyboard, mobaxterm

I would like to create a macro in MobaXterm that types some text and then pastes the IP address from my clipboard.

eg.

```
type: ssh -l username
send keypress: CTRL + V
```

Is this possible at all?